# How to list all files that refer the specific dll?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, namespaces, visual-studio-2019

I have a project with hundreds of dll references.

Now I have a dll named "Microsoft.Test.dll".

I want to get all the files in the project that reference the namespace "Microsoft.Test".

```
using Microsoft.Test;
```

Does visual studio have a function to query these files?

P.S. "Ctrl+F" is not what I want.

Comment: I had once written a tool for this, but this is not a trivial task (not public, sorry). You need to manually analyze the references within all binary files within a directory and then do a reverse lookup on that data structure.

Comment: Not all the usages could be found by using Namespace1, there might be classes which has been used like Namespace1.Class1. May I know why 'Find in Files' does not do the trick for you? While it can search for regular expressions and [show/keep the results like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-in-files?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#keep-results).